# bash: /usr/bin/perl: Argument list too long

Tags: bash

Can anyone explain what is going on here:

```
$ export a
$ a=`perl -e 'print "z"x1000000'`
$ a=`perl -e 'print "z"x1000000'`
bash: /usr/bin/perl: Argument list too long
$ a=`perl -e 'print "z"x1000000'`
$ a=`perl -e 'print "z"x1000000'`
bash: /usr/bin/perl: Argument list too long
```

(The perl one liner makes a string containing 1000000 zs).
Why is the command line too long for every second run?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

**Edit**

It seems the failing run unsets $a. The limit seems to be 131070. Lower than that there is no error.

Comment: Is it intentional that the `a=\`perl -e 'print "z"x1000000'\`` line appears twice.

Comment: `getconf` [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)... Among others...

Comment: $ getconf ARG_MAX = 2097152, so that is not the limit.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes: the commands and the output is exactly what I run and see in that order.

Comment: No, that is but one of the many limits applied to each exec - and they all combine to affect the behavior of an application when launched. It's why I provided the link. there is also LINE_MAX, for example, which prints 2k on my system, and, as my ARG_MAX is identical to yours, so might my LINE_MAX be. In any case, when you run `perl` the first time it adds all of that to the length of `$a` - and gets you beyond 1000000, then when you invoke it again the second time the length of its arguments + its environment exceeds ARG_MAX and so it fails - and resets `$a` to NUL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the limit on the size of arguments and environment variables passed to [execve](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

- POSIX specify it through `ARG_MAX`.
- Linux prior to kernel 2.6.23, the limit to 32 pages ([MAX_ARG_PAGES](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2005-January/msg00373.html)). With a 4-kB page size, the limit is 128kB.
- Linux kernel 2.6.23 and later, the limit is 1/4 of allowed stack size.

Note that there's also a limit for [maximum length and number of strings passed to execve](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h). It's hard-coded in linux source, and is applied regardless of allowed stack size.

You can see [man 2 execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) for more details.

On the second run, the Perl process doesn't start, so the command substitution `` `perl …` `` produces empty output and `a` is set to an empty value, shrinking the environment back to a small size. Then the third command succeeds and sets the environment close to the size limit, and so on.

For more clearly, you can try `export a; a=$(yes | head -c128k)`, then no more external commands can be executed.

Comment: . <(seq 17 | parallel echo \''echo {};export ac{}=$(yes | head -c120k)'\' ) # works and 'env|wc' = 'getopt ARG_MAX' = 2 MB. 'ulimit -s' = 8 MB, so that fits with the 1/4 of stack size. I still do not see where the 128 KB limit per variable is from (I use Linux kernel 3.13.0).

Comment: @OleTange: It's the limit on size of single argument or environment variable string. It's 128 kiB regardless the size of stack.

Comment: Is there a place where I can find that documented?

Comment: @OleTange: read the link I gave in my answer. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h or read `man 2 execve`.